# How can a changing electric current in the Earth's magnetic field be used to raise your orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, kinematics, orbital-motion

Imagine you are on a space station orbiting the Earth. You are subject to small amounts of atmospheric drag, so you must occasionally boost your orbit higher, as it decays over time.

Now imagine you extend a conducting cable of length $L$ tethered to the spacecraft. Using batteries charged from solar power, you create an electric current in the cable; these moving electric charges create a magnetic field.

How strong does this magnetic field need to be to oppose the Earth's magnetic field and boost yourself into higher orbit (say, going from 100 km to 101 km)? How much current does this take?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework question. It sounds like you have a pretty decent grasp on the underlying phenomena, but here's an approximate draft of what the high-level steps of a calculation you're looking for might look like:

1. What's the delta-v you need to raise your periapsis by 1km?
2. What's the effective interval of time you get to raise it? What's the force you need?
3. It's the Lorentz/Ampere force that generates the delta-v, not "opposing magnetic field". What is the current you need to generate this force?

Is there anything specific in the underlying theory that you want us to explain? Otherwise, please update your question with your existing calculation and where you got stuck so we can point out a way forward.

Comment: It's not a homework question — you can feel free to check my StackOverflow profile for proof.  I don't have any existing calculations; this started as a thought experiment after reading about the 1996 STS tether experiment failure.

Comment: @JohnFeminella how would your StackOverflow profile matter in convincing me about whether your question fits under the homework&exercises category? You’re asking us do do a calculation here for you, this sure sounds like a homework question

Comment: Because someone who's been in industry for 25 years probably isn't doing physics homework. I don't know how to prove a negative like "this isn't homework" to you, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @JohnFeminella the “homework-and-exercises” tag on this site applies to more than just school / uni homework: it applies to questions where it’s better to guide the author to the answer rather than giving it away. If you were to ask about the possibility of such a device under certain assumptions, or if you already had a calculation that you were looking for an error in, or if you had questions about the equations that should go into your calculation, that would be a different story. Currently your question reads as “help me do a calculation”, that’s why I think it’s a homework question.